# Particle system color not set properly in Android build in Unity.

Tags: unity, android, textures, particles, materials

I want to set the color of "Particle System" that I add to a game object in run time. Both game object and particle system are created in run time too.

I have the following code that works well on PC when I run it... But the problem is that in "Android" builds, color does not set correctly and particles are always "pink".

It should be:

[image: [pic1]]

But in Android it seen as:

[image: [pic2]]

Here is the code I use:

```
GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);       
sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
sphere.AddComponent<ParticleSystem>();
var ps = sphere.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ps.startLifetime = 1;
ps.startSpeed = 0.01f;
ps.startSize = 0.03f;
ps.maxParticles = 10000;
ParticleSystemExtension.SetEmissionRate(ps, 10000);
var sh = ps.shape;
sh.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.Circle;
sh.radius = 0.69f;

var cbl = ps.colorOverLifetime;
cbl.enabled = true;
Color mater = Color.green;
cbl.color = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient(mater);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh God! I change my solution and it work fine!

At first I make an empty GameObject with ParticleSystem attached, then create a prefab of that. after that, I add this prefab to my scene and set the necessary properties to it and then deactivate that.

In my script, add a public GameObject and assigned it to my gameObject (called Ring) that was created before.

Then instatiate it by the following code:

```
GameObject ps = Instantiate(Ring);
```

then make `ps` the child of `sphere`s that I was creating in code:

```
 Ring.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = Color.green;
 GameObject ps = Instantiate(Ring);
 ps.transform.parent = sphere.transform;
 ps.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
 ps.SetActive(true);
```

And that's it! It works nice!